# MongoDB: How can i insert or update an object in nested array when document exists or insert document if it doesn't exist with single atomic update?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What i need to implement in a single operation:

- **If document exists**:

  - check if object exists in nested array:

    - yes -> update object inside array
    - no -> insert object into array
- **If document doesn't exist**:

  - insert a new document

---

Assume I have a collection with a single document:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2
    },
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "c": {
          "d": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "c": {
          "d": 2
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Case 1:** update object in nested array

Nested object (with id = 1) to be updated:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "c": {
    "d": 10
  }
}
```

Expected result:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "c": {
        "d": 10
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "c": {
        "d": 2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Case 2**: insert object into nested array

Object to be inserted:

```json
{
  "id": 3,
  "c": {
    "d": 3
  }
}
```

Expected result:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "c": {
        "d": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "c": {
        "d": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "c": {
        "d": 3
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Case 3**: Document with _id doesn't exist -> need to insert into collection:

Document to be inserted:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 2
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "c": {
        "d": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected result - collection of two documents:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2
    },
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "c": {
          "d": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "c": {
          "d": 2
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "a": 2,
      "b": 2
    },
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "c": {
          "d": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried to use updateOne() with aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  _id: {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      data: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $in: [
              1,
              "$data.id"
            ]
          },
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$data",
              in: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$this",
                  {
                    $cond: [
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$this.id",
                          1
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "id": 1,
                        "c": {
                          "d": 10
                        }
                      },
                      {}
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$data",
              [
                {
                  "id": 1,
                  "c": {
                    "d": 10
                  }
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  upsert: true
})
```

It works fine, but when document doesn't exist, i get an error: **"fail to run update: write exception: write errors: [$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing]"**

Сan anybody help?